# Performance difference between searching for entry by numeric ID vs. string (e.g. md5) ID

Tags: mysql, md5

For security purposes, I provide public ID's for the entries in a MySQL table, for example MD5 hashes.
How big a difference in query performance is there between searching for the private, numeric ID of an entry in that table vs. searching for the public ID, which is a string (e.g. 32 bytes, MD5) ?

Comment: If they're both indexed, probably not a great deal.  Try it!

Comment: As @OliCharlesworth said .. if the column keeping `MD5` string is indexed there will be no significant difference of searching performance between two of them

Comment: It didn't occur to me, thanks! How do you you remove an index from a table column, though?

Comment: a minor hit due to md5's having to be stored as strings and compared as such (even with indexes), whereas int/bigints can be compared directly in a single asm instruction. but theoretically both data types would hash down to the same type of values in the index anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The difference for searching is not that big if you create an index on the MD5.

But the index will be about 8 times bigger than your index on the numeric ID (assuming this is a 4 Byte int). For tables with many entries this could increase your storage and memory needs.

In some extreme cases (tables with very few other columns) you might need up to 8 times more disk space and memory to store that table.

Answer (score 0):

An int is 4 bytes; an md5 is 32 bytes. The int will be faster and take 7n bytes less space on disk. Not to mention, calculating md5, while pretty quick, still takes time.

With very few rows, unique index,  and normal db traffic, you probably won't notice much difference though.